# Not able to retrieve data from firebase in django

Tags: python, django, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to get data from Firebase into my Django app the issue i face is that some of the documents are retrieved and some aren't. A really weird thing I noticed is when on the admin page the documents that can be accessed are highlighted in a darker shade than the ones that we aren't able to get from the database.

[image]

The highlighted issue is shown in the image above. The first document is highlighted but the second isn't and the first is read by the django function below

```
def home(request, user=""):
db = firestore.client()

docs = db.collection(u'FIR_NCR').stream()
for doc in docs:
    print(doc.id,end="->")
    s = db.collection(u'FIR_NCR').document(u'{}'.format(doc.id)).collection(u'all_data').get()
    print(s[0].id,end="->")
    print(s[0].to_dict())
return render(request, "home.html", {"user":user})
```

In this *docs* is not able to get the complete list of the documents necessary and hence the issue.

It would be wonderful if someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong. T.I.A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document ID isn't actually highlighted.  The difference between the first and the second ID is that the second one is in *italics*.  That means **there is no actual document with that ID**.  The reason why the Firestore console shows you a document ID at all for a missing document is because it has a nested subcollection.  You can click into that missing document, then again click into the subcollection.

In Firestore, you can have subcollections nested under documents that don't exist.  This is OK.  Just be aware that these missing documents can't be discovered by a normal query in the collection where you see them in the console.

Comment: Hey what your saying is true, the one in italics has a nested collection. Is there any docs or resource you know that helps to query a missing document?

Comment: It's not possible to query for things that aren't present using the web and mobile client SDKs.  You will need a backend SDK for that.  For example, nodejs provides: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#listDocuments